# Difference between gateway.push.apple.com and api.push.apple.com

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications

What is the exact difference between gateway.push.apple.com and api.push.apple.com

I am able to send test notification using gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 
But for production gateway.push.apple.com is not working

Answer (score 2):

The **api.push.apple.com** is the new API for Sending Notification Requests from APNs, but **gateway.push.apple.com** is still working no worries XD, you just have to ensure to complete all process about the signed certificates, first of all, follow the next steps from you **aps.cer** downloaded from App Store Connect.

```
# Convert the .cer file into a .pem file:
$ openssl x509 -in aps.cer -inform der -out PushChatCert.pem

# Convert the private key’s .p12 file into a .pem file:
$ openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in PushChatKey.p12 -out PushChatKey.pem

# Finally, combine the certificate and key into a single .pem file
$ cat PushChatCert.pem PushChatKey.pem > ck.pem

# At this point it’s a good idea to test whether the certificate works.
$ telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195

# Let’s try connecting again, this time using our SSL certificate and private 
key to set up a secure connection.
$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert 
PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem
```

Don't forget to choose the right API URL in production: **gateway.push.apple.com**
and the **MOST** important don't forget this Push Notifications configuration only works when the app is TestFlight or is Published for Dev you could use **gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com**